# What is the correct order to hit the direction lock in the sand ship?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the brig of the sandship, there is a directional lock.

[image]

There are ship wheels on the ground which surely reveal the correct order. I see that they have red spokes which signify the order to read them, but when I try the directions they show (LEFT RIGHT LEFT DOWN) the lock won't budge! Am I not interpreting them correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of giving it away, I'll start by giving you a hint, followed by the issue you are having in spoiler tags, and finally followed by the answer in spoiler tags at the bottom.

My hint is to look at the ship wheels hanging on the wall next to the door.

> The issue you have is that you are reading the ship wheels wrong. The part of the wheel with the **red outline** is the top of the wheel. That is what you should used in order to determine the position of coloured section which details the correct order. For example, the below picture indicates you should hit the **bottom** piece on the key.

[image]

Finally, if you still cannot figure it out, here is the correct order:

> The order is: **Bottom, Top, Bottom, Right**.

(image: screen shot from [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS6PRadcmG8) video)

Comment: Ah, of course. I was looking at the wheels from the wrong direction!

Answer (score -1):

The red spokes go on top, and the blue arrow is the right direction

Comment: Could you clarify a bit better?